# Why do Ruby and JavaScript bitwise operators yield different results with the same operands?

Tags: javascript, ruby, bit-manipulation

Why do Ruby and JavaScript bitwise operators yield different results with the same operands?

For example:

```
256 >> -4 # => 4096 (Ruby)
256 >> -4 # => 0 (Javascript)
```

Any tips/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Which is the one you expect? You could just ask for the other one.

Comment: I'm trying to port a Javascript program to a Ruby implementation, so I guess I'm looking to achieve the Javascript result in Ruby. Mainly I want to understand why they would give two different results in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the Ruby version, it looks like `256 >> -4` is equivalent to `256 << 4`, so the negative operand essentially just switches the direction of the shift.

From looking at the [ECMAScript specification for the right-shift operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.2), in JavaScript, the operand is converted to an unsigned 32-bit integer before the shift, so the `-4` becomes `4294967292`.  After this conversion the 5 least-significant bits are used for the shift, in other words we would end up shifting by `4294967292 & 0x1f` bits (which comes out to `28`).  It probably shouldn't surprise you at all to see that `256 >> 28` gives `0`.

For convenience, here is the text from the spec (steps 6 and 7 are most relevant to your confusion here):

> **The Signed Right Shift Operator ( `>>` )**
>
> Performs a sign-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left operand by the amount specified by the right operand.
>
> The production *ShiftExpression* : *ShiftExpression* >> *AdditiveExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating *ShiftExpression*.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating *AdditiveExpression*.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. Let `lnum` be `ToInt32(lval)`.
> 6. Let `rnum` be `ToUint32(rval)`.
> 7. Let `shiftCount` be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of `rnum`, that is, compute `rnum & 0x1F`.
> 8. Return the result of performing a sign-extending right shift of `lnum` by `shiftCount` bits. The most significant bit is propagated. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

As a side note, if you want to play around with this by converting a value to an unsigned 32-bit integer you can use `val >>> 0` as seen in [touint32.js](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/test/mjsunit/touint32.js) from V8 JavaScript Engine.